# Openl2tp make on CentOS

Tags: makefile, vpn, centos6

Im trying to install [`openl2tp`](http://www.openl2tp.org/) on CentOS.I have downloaded the source from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openl2tp/) but when i try to run `make` it gives me the following error

```
gin.o l2tp_event.o l2tp_test.o md5.o l2tp_api.o l2tp_rpc_server.o l2tp_rpc_xdr.o l2tp_config_token.o l2tp_config_parse.o -Wl,-E -L. -Lusl -lusl -ldl  -lc -lfl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [openl2tpd] Error 1
```

can someone guide me what im doing wrong...
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libfl is from the flex package. Try installing flex-devel.

Comment: thanks for your time can u provide me some example hw cn i start and stop the server...